# How to get "Don't Starve" game to work from its .rar file?

Tags: games

I am trying to get Don't starve for my Samsung Chromebook with Ubuntu and I can't figure out if i can play it since it's a .rar file. If anybody knows please let me know.

Comment: Note to close voters and reviewers: If you close this as a duplicate, ***make sure that the duplicate post addresses dealing with RAR files***.  This is an instance where posts about handling .tar files will not work, as it specifically needs `unrar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `.rar` file is basically the same as a `.zip` compressed folder.  It doesn't run the game, it probably extracts the game or an installer for the game.

You will need to read up on the exact procedures for installing the game, but to extract the `.rar` you can do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
cd /path/to/rar/file/
unrar e file.rar
```

Replace `/path/to/rar/file/` with the path to the folder that the `.rar` exists in.  Then, replace `file.rar` with the actual filename.  This will extract the `.rar` file's contents.

---

However, as I have said, you will need to look at the `README` for the specific program, or its `INSTALL` guide to know how to either run or install the game, after the files in the `.rar` are extracted.

Comment: for the sudo apt-get install unrar it says "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: @tattyfishpickle that means you either have `synaptic` open, you have `Update Manager` running, you have `Software Center` running, or you didn't use `sudo` when you used the `apt-get` command.